# A universe of Greek gods/goddesses, set in modern time (3 book series)

Tags: story-identification

The series had three books.  A universe of Greek gods/goddesses, set in modern time.

The gods steal Titans and force them to assume the form of infants/children, and raise them as mundanes in a boarding school type situation.  The protagonist is a young woman who discovers she can travel through the fourth and fifth dimensions as her power.  Her companions: a fey, can travel by unseen ways to various locations; a boy-shaman raised under the traditions of science, can cause anything he wants to happen simply by wishing it and tries to recreate the Michelson–Morley experiment. She ultimately discovers the true nature of the universe she is in and that the deities all follow some sort of rock-papers-scissors system where each deity has a corresponding type which he is weak to, and strong against.

What is the name of this series?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chronicles of Chaos by John C. Wright.

Orphans of Chaos

Fugitives of Chaos

Titans of Chaos