# Book: Handful of children kept in a school as political mythological prisoners

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a book I read once from the high school library.

It starts off with a handful of children in a special school, they are the only students of this school, and they have lived there all their lives. They turn a certain age and find out that they aren't human, each of them is some magical or mythological creature, like a cyclops(which were logic/technological based) or witch(who used rhymes/chants to call out their power).

They end up using their new found powers to rebel against the teachers and escape the school.

I remember that they are each in some way very important to each of the different races they belong to, like children of the chief/leader. They were all kept in the school to keep the peace between the different races.

I realize that's not really much to go on, sorry.

Comment: It sounds awfully close to John C. Wright's *Orphans of Chaos* (2005) if someone wants to check out the details.

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents: yes it's Orphans of Chaos. I'll dig out the book in search of supporting quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A universe of Greek gods/goddesses, set in modern time (3 book series)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46317/a-universe-of-greek-gods-goddesses-set-in-modern-time-3-book-series)

Comment: Note that proposed duplicate target is already the target of a different duplicate (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155240/story-with-a-multidimensional-girl)

Comment: @Otis - this one has a much better answer. Let's close them the other way around instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book is the first book in the [Orphans of Chaos trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicles_of_Chaos_(fantasy_trilogy)) by John C. Wright.

The series is loosely based on Greek mythology and the children are offspring of beings analogous to the [Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(mythology)) and are being held captive by other beings analogous to the [Olympian gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Olympians). They are being held as hostages to prevent the outbreak of war between the two sides.

There are five children involved. Initially they are just given numeric names Primus, Secunda, etc, but are allowed to choose their own names when they get old enough. The narrator is Amelia Armstrong Windrose (originally Secunda) who chose her name in honour of Amelia Earhart.

When the children discover they are being held as hostages they plan an escape, but at the end of the first book the escape fails and they are recaptured.

The powers of the children, and the other characters in the book, don't map precisely to the powers of the Greek deities because they aren't literally the deities, just similar beings. For example Amelia's power is that she can perceive a fourth spatial dimension.